# pm2 error: typeerror: one of the pids provided is invalid

Tags: reactjs, pm2

If i use serve build 80 --spa then it runs fine and site is reachable successfully , but when I use sudo pm2 serve build 80 --spa, or pm2 serve build 80 --spa, i mean when i use pm2 to serve my reactjs build, then it shows problem in pm2 logs and site is not reachable. What is the solution for this ?

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-194:~/workspace/frontend$ pm2 serve build 80 --spa
[PM2] Starting /usr/local/lib/node_modules/pm2/lib/API/Serve.js in fork_mode (1 instance)
[PM2] Done.
[PM2] Serving /home/ubuntu/workspace/frontend/build on port 80
┌────┬──────────────────────────┬─────────────┬─────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────┬──────┬───────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┬──────────┐
│ id │ name                     │ namespace   │ version │ mode    │ pid      │ uptime │ ↺    │ status    │ cpu      │ mem      │ user     │ watching │
├────┼──────────────────────────┼─────────────┼─────────┼─────────┼──────────┼────────┼──────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┤
│ 0  │ static-page-server-80    │ default     │ 5.3.0   │ fork    │ N/A      │ 0s     │ 0    │ online    │ 0%       │ 0b       │ ubuntu   │ disabled │
└────┴──────────────────────────┴─────────────┴─────────┴─────────┴──────────┴────────┴──────┴───────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┴──────────┘
[PM2][WARN] Current process list is not synchronized with saved list. App static-page-server-8080 server differs. Type 'pm2 save' to synchronize.
ubuntu@ip-172-31-42-194:~/workspace/frontend$ pm2 logs
[TAILING] Tailing last 15 lines for [all] processes (change the value with --lines option)
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/pm2.log last 15 lines:
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:55:23: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:55:54: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:55:54: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:56:24: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:56:24: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:56:54: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:56:54: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:57:24: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:57:24: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:57:54: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:57:54: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:58:24: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:58:24: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:58:34: PM2 error: Error caught while calling pidusage
PM2        | 2023-09-01T07:58:34: PM2 error: TypeError: One of the pids provided is invalid

/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/static-page-server-80-out.log last 15 lines:
/home/ubuntu/.pm2/logs/static-page-server-80-error.log last 15 lines:
```

I want to run my build using pm2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same issue recently and was able to resolve it by following these steps:

1. Remove node_modules

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

2. Remove package-lock.json

```
rm package-lock.json
```

3. Run npm install

```
npm install
```

Not sure why this issue occurs, But I tried reinstalling pm2 and then above given steps, After that I started my app again. And it solved the issue for me.

I found these steps on a GitHub issue discussion. You can read the original discussion and more insights at this link: [GitHub Issue #3873](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/3873).

You can also read this comment: [GitHub Issue #5496](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/5496#issuecomment-1528704773)

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem this afternoon. messed around and found out that it is related to the package version. The version I was using, which had this pid problem, was 5.3.1.
I managed to get rid of it by downgrading to 5.2.0
Not sure if it works for other people.